# Is it possible to find a JWT token is expired in Django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Is it possible to find whether a JWT token is expired or not when both authentication_classes and permission_classes classes are present? Suggestions showing that try with simplejwt exception class. But when I tried with exception class it showed that the reference is not present.

I have tried this code.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import TokenExpiredError, InvalidToken
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import TokenError
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication

try:
    # `request` is the current request object
    JWTAuthentication().authenticate(request)
except TokenError as e:
    if isinstance(e, TokenExpiredError):
        # Expired token
        print("Token has expired")
    elif isinstance(e, InvalidToken):
        # Token is invalid for some other reason
        print("Invalid token")
    else:
        # Any other error
        print("Token error:", str(e))
```

if you do not have `djangorestframework-simplejwt` installed, please use the following command:

`pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt`